# Shorten $\frac{n}{n^\frac{1}{2}}$?

Tags: fractions

I have a short question to solve my problem.

Can I simplify $\frac{n}{n^\frac{1}{2}}$ ?

Thanks already for answers.

Comment: Do you mean simplify?  $n/(n^{1/2})=n^{1/2}$.

Comment: You can either rewrite as $\frac{n^{\frac12}n^{\frac12}}{n^{\frac12}}$ and cancel, or use exponent rules: $\frac n{n^{\frac12}}=n^1\cdot n^{-\frac12}=n^{1-\frac12}=n^{\frac12}$

Comment: that's already what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $n\ne 0$,

$$\frac{n}{n^{1/2}}=\frac{n^{1/2}n^{1/2}}{n^{1/2}}=n^{1/2}\left(\frac{n^{1/2}}{n^{1/2}}\right)=n^{1/2}$$